# \ufeff on writing and reading a csv file on visualstudio

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, csv

I'm trying to write a field on a csv file and then print it on the console, however when printing the first line after writing it, it shows a number 10 (which i'm not adding to the field. Then when i'm just reading the file and printing it the second line shows what I was supposed to write on the first attempt but showing \ufeff

Here is the code

```
from csv import DictReader

with open('loopbacks2.csv', mode='r+', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
    client_details = DictReader(csv_file)
    for client in client_details:
        client['State'] = csv_file.write('Completed')
        print(client)
```

Original csv file looks like this

```
Name,Loopback,Object,IP,SSH,State
Device1,192.168.1.2,host1,8.7.6.5/32,2022
Device2,192.168.1.3,host2,8.7.7.2/32,2222
```

When running the script, this is the output

```
{'Name': 'Device1', 'Loopback': '192.168.1.2', 'Object': 'host1', 'IP': '8.6.5.6/32', 'SSH': '2022', 'State': 10}
```

Then I open the file and it looks like this

```
Name,Loopback,Object,IP,SSH,State
Device1,192.168.1.2,host1,8.7.6.5/32,2022
Device2,192.168.1.3,host2,8.7.7.2/32,2222,Completed
```

Then if i comment the writing part and just print it like this code

```
from csv import DictReader

with open('loopbacks2.csv', mode='r+', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
    client_details = DictReader(csv_file)
    for client in client_details:
        #client['State'] = csv_file.write('Completed')
        print(client)
```

Then the prompt shows this

```
{'Name': 'Device1', 'Loopback': '192.168.1.2', 'Object': 'host1', 'IP': '8.6.5.6/32', 'SSH': '2022', 'State': ''}

{'Name': 'Device1', 'Loopback': '192.168.1.2', 'Object': 'host1', 'IP': '8.6.5.6/32', 'SSH': '2022', 'State': '\ufeffCompleted'}
```

what am I missing or confusing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot edit a file by reading a line, modifying the line, then writing that same line back in the original file.

What's happening in your code:

```py
client['State'] = csv_file.write('Completed')
print(client)
```

is that you are telling Python to write (to the end of the file) the string 'Completed', which is 10 bytes long.  That's the `10` that is being returned from `write()` and set in `client['State']`, which you see in the `print()` statement.  And after the script has run and the file is closed, it has 'Completed' at the end.

To edit a file:

1. read the original file
2. find the data you want to modify
3. modify that data
4. write the modified data to ***a new file***

and then if you want to overwrite the original with the new, do that.

Here's how that looks with Python's **DictReader** and **DictWriter**:

```py
import csv

data = []
with open('input.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        row['State'] = 'Completed'
        data.append(row)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=data[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Also, `\ufeff` is the BOM ([wiki: UTF-8 Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark)) that's written at the beginning of every file when you specify `utf-8-sig`, your first call to `csv_file.write(...)` added that.

Comment: Thank you! it worked great